# How to share image and text on whatsapp using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello till now i can share my content on whatsapp using javascript code but still not able to share image with text. Does anyone done it? Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", '.mct_whatsapp_btn', function() {
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      var text = $(this).attr("data-text");
      var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
      var message = encodeURIComponent(text) + " - " + encodeURIComponent(url);
      var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
      window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
    } else {
      alert("Please use an Mobile Device to Share this Article");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: is it a cordova application? do you get any console errors?

Comment: no its not cordova application its simple HTML view

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to do this from browser then as per whatsapp docs, you can only send text or link through this. read it here :
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

If you want to send image with this whatsapp protocol, you can first upload image to your server and then use 'encodeURIComponent' to send link with this:

```
'whatsapp://send?text='+encodeURIComponent(imageURL)
```

As already pointed by @Akis, for using it in hybrid app framework like cordova/ionic, its better if you search for plugin to achieve this.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Above link with cordova plugin might help you in that.

Comment: It sends the image as link, whereas I want image to be sent as image. How can that be done?

Comment: above mentioned cordova plugin can help you do that. read the documentation for it.
window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, 'www/image.gif', null);
For Ionic 4+ usage is given here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing