# Web - Whatsapp button / Send image

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

I am using the WhatsApp function to send (from my website) a text to an already determined number, and I would like to know if there is any way to add a url so that an image can also be included in the entire message.

**My current code is a traditional format:**

```
<a href="https://wa.me/111222333?text=Hi%20*all*%20!%20...%20I%20need%20add%20a%20code%20here%20to%20send%20an%20image">

<div id="send">SEND</div>

</a>
```

Is there a way to add an image to send along with the text?

**NOTE:** The image I want to send is on my own server.

Thanks in advance!

:)

Comment: Hi Pablo, maybe this can help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435020/how-to-share-image-and-text-on-whatsapp-using-javascript

Comment: Simply you can't send image  directly to whatsapp. There is no api for this. But you should check this https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp